# Find external source URL in YouTube analytics

Tags: youtube

One of my videos has seen an unexpected spike in traffic and 98% of this traffic is coming from a forum post.

I want to see the post so I can understand why people were directed there but I can see no way of finding the URL. Searching the entire site for keywords from my video brings up thousands of results.

Is there an easy way of finding this? Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 2):

It used to have this feature, but it no longer does. It will only show you the domain name, not the full url.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/8vT9sT2PdA4